# USB 3.0 ethernet dongle periodically disconnects from network

Tags: debian, usb, ethernet, laptop

I have an Asus UX305FA notebook that lacks an Ethernet port, so I ordered an [Aukey 3 port USB 3.0 hub with Ethernet](https://www.amazon.co.uk/AUKEY-Gigabit-Ethernet-Compatible-Windows/dp/B00VFVMFJ2/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1500760230&sr=8-1&keywords=AUKEY+USB+Hub+3+Ports+USB+3.0+with+Gigabit) .

Until recently I had the notebook running Linux Mint 18.1 XFCE.  The Ethernet connection would cut out periodically and would re-establish a few seconds later.  I've recently installed Debian Jessie XFCE (running a 4.9 kernel from backports) and the connection is still lost periodically but it is not re-established until a reboot.  I have a keyboard and mouse connected to the USB hub which continue to operate as normal when the Ethernet connection is lost.

How can I determine if the disconnections are due to a hardware issue or a configuration problem?  I suspect that it may be a combination of the two...

Output of `lsusb`:

```
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 0bda:8153 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 2109:0812
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 064e:9700 Suyin Corp.
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp.
Bus 001 Device 014: ID 045e:0040 Microsoft Corp. Wheel Mouse Optical
Bus 001 Device 015: ID 2109:2812
Bus 001 Device 013: ID 05af:8277 Jing-Mold Enterprise Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Output of `ethtool -i eth0`:

```
driver: r8152
version: v1.08.7
firmware-version: 
bus-info: usb-0000:00:14.0-3.4
supports-statistics: yes
supports-test: no
supports-eeprom-access: no
supports-register-dump: no
supports-priv-flags: no
```

Output of `dmesg`:

```
[ 3582.224511] net_ratelimit: 25 callbacks suppressed
[ 3582.224522] r8152 2-3.4:1.0 eth0: Tx status -71
[ 3582.227983] r8152 2-3.4:1.0 eth0: Tx status -71
[ 3582.523946] r8152 2-3.4:1.0 eth0: Tx status -71
[ 3583.547979] r8152 2-3.4:1.0 eth0: Tx status -71
[ 3584.571929] r8152 2-3.4:1.0 eth0: Tx status -71
```

**EDIT:** Following further research, I have found that others have also had similar issues with USB Ethernet interfaces which use the Realtek 8153 chipset.  I have since tried the following in the hope of finding a solution, but I have not yet been successful:

- Disabling autosuspend for all USB devices via GRUB.
- Creation of `udev` rules to prevent USB power suspension for specific devices.
- Installation of a newer driver (2.08.0) from the Realtek website.

Can anybody suggest something else I could try?

**EDIT 2:** I updated to Debian Stretch and still had the same issue, so I purchased a [different Ethernet adaptor](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Plugable-Gigabit-Ethernet-Network-Adapter/dp/B00AQM8586/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1500760133&sr=8-1&keywords=Plugable+USB+3.0+to+10%2F100%2F1000+Gigabit+Ethernet).  Fortunately this one works without any problems!

Comment: What Ethernet chipset does the external USB hub have?

Comment: Welcome to U&L , please add the `lsusb` output

Comment: Unclear what's meant by "connection drops". What's in `dmesg` or `/var/log/messages` at the time of the disconnects?